# Next.js & React - Google Tag Manager "Page view" trigger won't fire on every page

Tags: reactjs, google-tag-manager, next.js

I'm having issues with the "Page view" trigger on GTM with Next.js and React. If there is a page where the template is reused and only the data changes, the trigger won't fire. I've tried putting the GTM script in the head component, and loading it with the react-gtm-module package. Both result in the same problem. I came up with a temporary fix where I fire the tags on "All Pages" and on "History Change" when the url path is one of the problematic ones. This is a lot better but still not consistent. Any help with figuring this out would be very much appreciated.

Comment: You can implement it in GTM using a page history trigger: https://www.analyticsmania.com/post/single-page-web-app-with-google-tag-manager/ It seems like you can't (or google has made it really difficult) to manually trigger a GTM Page View after the first one has initially fired.

Answer (score 1):

GTM "All pages" actually reflects document load event so it's ok not to fire with a reused template. you may want to push a custom object to dataLayer to let GTM know that page was changed. For example, you may call in your template

```
dataLayer.push({'event':'pageview'});
```

and then use GTM custom event trigger for `pageview` event.

Comment: Thank you. That sounds like a good idea. If the page is reused for another view, would that event fire again?

Comment: you may control this in GTM. GTM trigger may fire once per pageview or exactly with each dataLayer push

Comment: it seems like you can only use this on each page load, so if you have a SPA you can't fire this again after the user has changed route :(

also the event was 'gtm.js' in my case, I think it's the default "Page View" in GTM.

Comment: @OZZIE Then what we can do to force it to fire on each page route push? Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

History change event will make that trick

Comment: could you elaborate further on this?